# Code runs after assigning the returned value to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, return

```
def something():
    final = "95"
    print(final)
    return final
something_123 = something()
```

I am returning the variable `final`, and assigning it (the returned value) to something_123 because i've read that its better to assign the returned value to a variable rather than not for some reason. Why does this cause my function to run?

Comment: It doesn't cause your function to run. In any case, if you don't assign the return value to a function, how else would you use it?

Comment: it does, when i run this piece of code, my function does what it promises to do

Comment: No, if you remove the assignment, and just do `something()` then your function will still run

Answer (score 1):

Your function runs because you called it on the right hand side - `something()`. Whether you should have  a return value that you assign to a variable depends on what that function does. in this case, it calculates and prints something. If you want to use that value later, then yes, you'd return it like your code shows. If you don't care about the return value, then don't return one or assign it to anything.

Comment: how would i return my value and then assign it to a variable with out causing the function to run? also, why is it needed/recommended to assign a returned value to a variable?

Comment: Since running the function creates the value, it needs to run. You may be thinking about global variables that exist outside of a function and can be initialized any time. Functions can read global variables just by using its name. If the function wants to write a global variable, it must first be marked with the `global` keyword in the function. Global variables have a lot of uses, and its common to read them in functions. But assigning them in functions is usually a poor design choice as you restrict the usefulness of the function and it becomes unclear what your code is doing.

Comment: `global` is evil, thats why im using `return`